# MediaPlayer audio streaming fails on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, media-player, tablet, galaxy

I have some issue playing streaming* audio on a Galaxy Tab (works on HTC Desire HD and Nexus One). When I create the MediaPlayer object, it produces an error like this:

```
02-09 02:21:39.088: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(9325): native_setup
02-09 02:21:39.088: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(9325): constructor
02-09 02:21:39.088: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(9325): setListener
02-09 02:21:39.092: INFO/MediaPlayer(9325): uri is:http://147.83.39.86:3200/osgi/files/TTS/1297185775715.ogg
02-09 02:21:39.092: INFO/MediaPlayer(9325): path is null
02-09 02:21:39.092: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
02-09 02:21:39.092: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(9325): setDataSource: path http://147.83.39.86:3200/osgi/files/TTS/1297185775715.ogg
02-09 02:21:39.092: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(9325): setDataSource(http://147.83.39.86:3200/osgi/files/TTS/1297185775715.ogg)
02-09 02:21:39.092: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(2392): Failed to create player object
02-09 02:21:39.092: ERROR/MediaPlayer(9325): Unable to to create media player
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325): create failed:
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:745)
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:675)
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:611)
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:592)
02-09 02:21:39.104: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(9325):     at com.vodafone.inredis.movil.interfazweb.InredisWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(InredisWebViewClient.java:37)
```

And this is how I create the MediaPlayer object, nothing weird:

```
Uri tempPath = Uri.parse(url);
player = MediaPlayer.create(interfazWeb, tempPath);
if (player != null){
  player.start();
} else {
  Log.e(TAG, "No se puede abrir el audio:" + url);
}
return true;
```

And to provide more information, I can say I tested the url passed, and I can download it with the native browser and play it normally. Obviously I can play it with my desktop browser.

Has anyboedy experienced this problem with the mentioned device?

Thanks in advance.

######## EDIT ##############

I haven't solved this issue yet, but I've been researching a bit, now I'm downloading the file in a separate thread, saving it to a temp file and opening with the `MediaPlayer`. It produces another kind of error, I'm suspecting of the file folders and permissions, but I'm not sure yet.

So now I have those temp files which I can play with the galaxy's native player, but not with the one I create in my code, and a different piece of log trace, which gives me no hint.

```
02-10 01:36:36.945: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(8371): native_setup
02-10 01:36:36.945: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): constructor
02-10 01:36:36.945: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): setListener
02-10 01:36:36.948: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(8371): setDataSource: path /sdcard/audioTmp360988.ogg
02-10 01:36:36.948: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): setDataSource(/sdcard/audioTmp360988.ogg)
02-10 01:36:36.952: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): prepare
02-10 01:36:36.952: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(2394): Client::notify In
02-10 01:36:36.952: ERROR/MediaPlayer(8371): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-10 01:36:36.952: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): prepared
02-10 01:36:36.952: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): signal application thread
02-10 01:36:36.952: ERROR/MediaPlayer(8371): callback application
02-10 01:36:36.952: ERROR/MediaPlayer(8371): back from callback
02-10 01:36:36.952: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): prepare complete - status=0
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(8371): native_finalize
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer-JNI(8371): release
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): setListener
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): disconnect
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): destructor
02-10 01:36:41.437: VERBOSE/MediaPlayer(8371): disconnect
```

Come on, I can't be the only one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV and OGG Audio Streaming with MediaPlayer does not work on Samsung Galaxy TAB (with FroYo). I've been testing, and I used the API Demo (8), specifically this piece of code at `/Demos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.java`:

```
    private void playAudio(Integer media) {
        try {
            switch (media) {
                case LOCAL_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Set the path variable to a local audio file path.
                     */
//                  path = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg";
//                  path = "http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3";
                    path = "http://www.nch.com.au/acm/8k16bitpcm.wav";
                    if (path == "") {
                        // Tell the user to provide an audio file URL.
                        Toast
                                .makeText(
                                        MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.this,
                                        "Please edit MediaPlayer_Audio Activity, "
                                                + "and set the path variable to your audio file path."
                                                + " Your audio file must be stored on sdcard.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    Uri tempUri = Uri.parse(path);
                    try {
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, tempUri);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    break;
                case RESOURCES_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Upload a audio file to res/raw folder and provide
                     * its resid in MediaPlayer.create() method.
                     */
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

            }
            tx.setText("Playing audio...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
```

I just changed those 3 lines defining the path of the file to play, anything else on the project. Well, only the Mp3 file would play, both WAV and OGG produce and exception similar to the one on my question.

Would anybody else like to try? Should I assume there is a bug?

Comment: Just to add some more info, I asked a friend of mine to test it on a Galaxy S, and it happens the same

Answer (score 0):

my audio file encoded with AudioEncoder.AMR_NB,the file can be played in the 3G,but cann't played in Wifi,Mp3 file can be played in all.so I guess file format affect the result.